# iPhone SDK: does anybody know how to resize uiimage on scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

Does anybody know how to resize an UIImage on top of an UITableView on scrolling down.

something like this [Youtube link: Velox](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4cMnFciSSo&t=2m49s)

[at `2:49` you see what i mean]

or like the Navigation Bar in the iOS7 Update of `Instagram`

Comment: Implement the scrollview delegate, listen to `scrollViewDidScroll:` and after a certain threshold, start resizing your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your view controller a [UIScrollViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) and respond to

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Within the delegate method you can use

```
CGFloat offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
```

To get how far the scroll view has moved from its original position, and resize the UIImage accordingly.

[This](https://github.com/objective-awesome/ParallaxHeaderTableViewController) github project shows how you can add an image above a TableView and adjust the image as it scrolls.  The difference is that instead of resizing the image, it is moved so that there is a parallax effect.  In [ParallaxHeaderTableViewController.m](https://github.com/objective-awesome/ParallaxHeaderTableViewController/blob/master/ParallaxHeaderTableView/ParallaxHeaderTableView/ParallaxHeaderTableViewController.m) you can change the scrollViewDidScroll method to resize the image instead of move it.

Comment: thanks a lot. exact what i have looked for.